# Creating Database using excel tables

Tags: sql

i have a data with 3 diffrent table in excel sheets and i dont have a relation between them and i need to fix the relation between i have a table like trains stops,property,school details in the with the laltitude and longitudes columns with diffetent value

i tried doing the data relation betweet them with latitude and longitude
but i think need to find the radius but im not getting a right approach how to continue

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: You say you need relation between train stops. While this could be partially doable from geographical data, it does not truly says anything about real relations between stations. Any result will have to be at least checked manually and probably corrected.